# Everybody elses definition of the right-shift bitwise operator is different from w3schools.com. What am I missing?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

w3schools.com [define](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_bitwise_operators.asp) the right-shift bitwise operator for Python as 'shift right by pushing copies of the leftmost bit in from the left, and let the rightmost bits fall off'. What do they mean by 'pushing copies of the leftmost bit in from the left'? More specifically, what do they mean by 'the leftmost bit'? Are they just refering to zeros? I know that I am missing something or a lot of things. If you could, please help me understand.

Comment: That w3schools page is simply wrong, both for left shift and right shift. Python ints aren't fixed width, so as you surmise the notion of "leftmost bit" doesn't make sense for Python ints.

Comment: W3schools has a reputation for often being wrong or misleading. You are probably better off ignoring them, not just for Python advice.

Answer (score 2):

The w3schools.com definition is more descriptive of Python 2, which had 32-bit integers: 1 bit for the sign (leftmost) and 31 bits for the magnitude, in twos-complement.

So when it says 'pushing copies of the leftmost bit' it means that the sign bit is propagated rightwards, so that right-shifting a negative number returns a value that is still negative.

For example, in Python 2, if you take the largest possible (as in, furthest from zero) negative integer (meaning `int`):

```
>>> i = -sys.maxint - 1
>>> i
-2147483648
```

and you then shift it to the right, you still get a negative number:

```
>>> i >> 16
-32768
```

which you would not get if all of the bits, including the sign bit, were shifted right and replaced with zeroes: you would get 32768 (0x00008000) instead.

If you instead shift `i` one bit to the left, that would cause underflow in a 32-bit integer (because a zero would be shifted into the sign bit, making it positive, and the magnitude would be all zeroes). Python 2 protects you from this by coercing `i` to a Python 2 `long`:

```
>>> i << 1
-4294967296L
```

A Python 2 `long` is pretty well the same as a Python 3 integer.

Because Python 3 took extraordinary care to keep the behaviour of the shift operators the same as Python 2, you will get the same result if you shift a Python 3 integer 16 places to the right.

But the mechanism is different. The shift operator works on a *notional* bit representation of the integer. The documentation phrases it like this: note the phrase *as though*:

> The result of bitwise operations is calculated as though carried out in two’s complement with an infinite number of sign bits.

A Python integer isn't really represented internally by a variable-length twos-complement binary number: the magnitude is a sequence of 30-bit digits, with the sign stored separately, but it's best not to fret about that overmuch. The shift operator gives results based on the *notional* representation, not the actual physical one.

As an aside, whenever you are in doubt about a topic like this, it is really best to go straight to the Python documentation, which is always accurate and nearly always exemplary. Python's popularity attracts bloggers, some of whom have an insecure grasp of their subject, and 3rd-party tutorial material often bears traces of inadequate revision of what was originally written for Python 2.

Comment: Nitpick: Python 2's `int` is either 32-bit or 64-bit, depending on platform. (Typically, it's 32-bit on Windows and 64-bit everywhere else.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have 4 bits, say `0 0 1 0`, then the left most bit is `0`.

If you have 4 bits, say `1 0 0 0`, then the left most bit is `1`.

Literally the bit furthest left.

According to that definition from W3, the left-most bit will be used when shifting right.

So if I have 4 bits, `1 0 1 0`, then shifting right, according to W3, results in `1 1 0 1`.

If I have 4 bits, `0 1 1 0`, then shifting right, according to W3, results in `0 0 1 1`.

But, this isn't actually always the case. It's implementation dependent.

For example, in C++, if you have an un-signed integer, then the leftmost bit is filled with 0s when you shift right. This is true even if the left-most bit is 1.

Comment: I did not downvote, but using python's command line: `>>> 10 >> 1` (the `1010`) the output is 5 which is `101`, not 13, which would be `1101`?

Comment: "in Python, a typical integer is 32 bits" <- This isn't true: Python's `int` type is not fixed width (ignoring the ancient Python 2, that is). That means that the whole notion of "leftmost bit" doesn't apply to Python ints. The w3schools page is simply wrong here.

Comment: Standard shift in every implementation I have ever seen uses zero for the new slot. This is not limited to Python, it's how this is generally implemented even on the CPU level.

Comment: @tripleee Us old timer assembly writers know there are two right shifts: Arithmetic shift right and logical shift right (ASR and LSR).  The logical shift right shifts in a zero for the incoming bit.  Arithmetic shift retains the sign bit (leftmost bit).   Python handles it as divide by two, more in line with the arithmetic shift.  In other words, if the shift were a logical shift, a negative number would effectively become a positive number on the first shift.